# 'currentQueryOptimization' parameter gives authorization failure

Tags: java, database, db2

I am trying to connect to a DB2 database from a Java application, works fine with plain jdbc url but it fails when I try to pass 'currentQueryOptimization' parameter.

This works

```
DriverManager.getConnection (jdbcUrl, username, password)
```

This does not work

```
DriverManager.getConnection (jdbcUrl, username, password+";currentQueryOptimization=9")
```

> com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlInvalidAuthorizationSpecException: [jcc][t4][2013][11249][3.66.46] Connection authorization failure occurred.
>   Reason: User ID or Password invalid. ERRORCODE=-4214, SQLSTATE=28000

My password does not contain any special characters, only alpha numerics. Has anybody faced this ? Any suggestions for me ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the `DriverManager` interface, should you use the pattern below to specify the properties?

```
getConnection(String url, java.util.Properties info);
```

per the suggestion in the docs at link below
[link](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc/src/tpc/imjcc_rjvdsprp.html)